# How to link javascript / css files in main app directory in IOS from html file in ApplicationStorageDirectory in Adobe Air

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, air, adobe

I'm using Adobe Air for IOS offline app, and I want to implement a download updates (html files + js,css) feature from within the application. The files would be displayed in a StageWebView component.

Since Apple doesn't allow saving files inside the installation directory, I must use ApplicationStorageDirectory instead to download files into.

I want those download html files to link to .js / .css files already installed within the main application directory (e.g. at myApp.app).

The reason for that is I want to minimize the number of the downloaded (shared) files as much as possible. Is this possible?

**EDIT 1:**

What I need is something like the following:

Inside ApplicationStoarageDirectory (/Library/Application Support/):

```
 test.html
```

I need it to link to a css file located inside ApplicationDirectory (installation directory), something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="**../../MyApp.app/**CSS/Templates.css" type="text/css" media="screen, mobile" title="main" charset="utf-8">
```

Thank you.

**EDIT 2:**

I had to copy everything I need in another place (application storage directory) and load from there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152170/using-html-js-file-saved-in-the-sandboxdocuments-directory-of-an-ios-app-so/13152725#13152725

Comment: Thanks @IshankDubey, I'm actually using Actionscript not Objective C.