# How to add JQuery plugin to UIWebview?

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, uiwebview, gantt-chart

I would like to know how I can add jQuery plugin (https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView) into the UIWebView as I want to display gantt chart with it?

Please tell me if there any tutorials or steps I  should follow?

Thanks, Kanishka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can have a `.html` file like -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TITLE</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Plugin.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="Plugin.css" rel="stylesheet"/>    
</head>
<body>
<div id="Pluginwrapper">

<div id="Plugincontainer"></div>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Have the `.html file, .js file and .css`(i.e. **All the plugin files**) file in the App bundle and, in order to display the content in `UIWebView`, just make the `.html` file and `.js` files as **Bundle Resources** in Xcode's **Build Phases Tab**.

Then use -

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"htmlfile" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Comment: I have added downloaded jquery.ganttView folder into the Resources directory in the application. Then create "sample.html" file and added all the plugin files into the "copy Bundle Resources". But simulator displays nothing!.Am I missing something here?

Comment: r u getting a compiler warning?

Comment: hmm, the path that u r giving in `src="jquery.ganttView.js` and `<link type="text/css" href="jquery.ganttView.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` seems not proper. The path is relative, so i recommend that u first try putting all the files in the App Bundle i.e. the left colum of the XCode ide  in a same folder instead of the Resorse App Sandbox..

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152170/using-html-js-file-saved-in-the-sandboxdocuments-directory-of-an-ios-app-so

Comment: No Ishank.I'm not getting any compiler warnings it just didn't display anything. I downloaded jquery.ganttView (gantt chart plugin) from the github and change the code like this, <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ganttView.js"></script><link type="text/css" href="jquery.ganttView.css" rel="stylesheet"/> and also the webview code to load the html file. Here is the source code (https://www.box.com/s/tsw7n8ca7kitxw5ax0cc)

Comment: Thanks @ishanak, finally its working! Thanks alot. Its seems I havent icluded proper java script in my "sample.html" file.Please let me know someone else need help on this.